# unable to install bitcoind (macOS, M1 chip)

Tags: mac, error, installation, make

I've been trying to install bitcoind on a new mac (Big Sur 11.4). I followed the instructions in doc/build-osx.md and installed all required dependencies, but when I try to run make, it gives me the following error:

```
Making all in src
  CXX      bitcoind-bitcoind.o
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fstack-clash-protection' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
In file included from bitcoind.cpp:14:
In file included from ./interfaces/chain.h:8:
./optional.h:10:10: fatal error: 'boost/optional.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [bitcoind-bitcoind.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Edit:
If I run brew install boost, it tells me it's already installed, but typing 'which boost' gives 'boost not found'.

Comment: are you sure you installed the `boost` dependency?

Comment: Well I didn't install it myself, but if I try 'brew install boost' it tells me it's already installed.

Comment: okay that was my first and only idea, cause i am not running macos - hope someone else can help

Comment: Is there any other info I can provide that might make it easier to diagnose the problem?

Comment: my guess now is, that your boost version might be too old - maybe [this comment on github](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/22482#issuecomment-883900780) helps

Comment: Have you followed the instructions at https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-osx.md? Is the mac one of the new ones with the M1 chip or an older one with an Intel processor?

Comment: Yep, that's the guide that I followed. And the mac is a newer one with an M1 chip.